# Separate each object in the array with a semicolon in NetSuite

Tags: jquery, arrays, split, netsuite

I'm successful in being able to create my array for adding multiple items to the cart, the problem I have is that I need to separate each object in the array with a semicolon.

Output: itemid1,value,itemid2, value

Expectation: itemid1,value;itemid2, value

```
    nval = "3";
    var multiArray = [];


    $('.partadd').click(function() {

   $('.partqty').each(function(id,value) {
    var value = this.value;
    var multiTerm = this.id+","+this.value;
    if(value < "1") { return false; }

    else { multiArray.push(multiTerm); }
    });

    var MultiURL = "/app/site/backend/additemtocart.nl?c=111111&n="+nval+"&qtyadd=1&buyid=multi&multi="+multiArray;
    console.log(MultiURL);

    if(multiArray == "") { alert('Parts cannot be added without quantity'); }
    });
```

For me to add multiple items to the cart, I have to organize by itemid and value.

I've tried `.split()` but I was getting errors stating that `.split()` was not a function. Is there another method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The join() method joins the elements of an array into a string, and returns the string.

You can use array.join(";") on multiArray that will return string

```
function myFunction() {
  var multiArray = ["id1,value1", "id2,value2", "id3,value3"];
  var multiArrayStr= multiArray.join(";");
  console.log(multiArrayStr);
}
```

Comment: How can I apply this when the array is being created? I'm using this an `.each` 
 function 

   `$('.partqty').each(function(id,value) {
    var value = this.value;
    var multiTerm = this.id+","+this.value;
 if(value < "1") { return false; }
 
 else { multiArray.push(multiTerm); }
 });` 

 I did try `.join`  after the push, it didn't do anything when I viewed the console.log

Comment: @JoshuaPrice-outside .each block you can use multiArray.join(";") and this will return string value

Comment: and I also believe that in MultiURL you want to pass **multiArray** as **temid1,value;itemid2, value**

Comment: I just added that outside the block, prior to calling "var MultiUrl", the console log still shows them being separated by a comma.

`   $('.partqty').each(function(id,value) {
    var value = this.value;
    var multiTerm = this.id+","+this.value;
 if(value < "1") { return false; }
 
 else { multiArray.push(multiTerm); }
 });
 
 multiArray.join(";");
 var MultiURL = "/app/site/backend/additemtocart.nl?c=337772&n="+nval+"&qtyadd=1&buyid=multi&multi="+multiArray;
 console.log(MultiURL);`

Comment: use new variable as **var multiArrayStr=multiArray.join(";");console.log(multiArrayStr);**

Comment: you're a lifesaver!!! I don't know why I didn't think of that. I think it was because I did the same thing, but with .split()

Comment: @JoshuaPrice- thanks..expecting to accept my answer.